# Arpping responding with Cisco ASA interface mac address and mac address of machine

Tags: cisco-asa, arp

For some reason our Cisco is responding to arp requests between machines on the same switch. It's not breaking anything but it is slowing initial connections. I've been making a lot of changes on the Cisco recently to configure a client and site 2 site vpn. The most recent being disabling nat between certain ip ranges. Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
devperf01b:~ sudo arping devperf01c
   ARPING 10.201.9.230
   60 bytes from 2c:33:11:2e:xx:xx (10.x.9.230): index=0 
     time=214.100 usec
     60 bytes from 18:03:73:be:xx:xx (10.x.9.230): index=1 
     time=257.969 usec
```

Comment: Do you have proxy ARP enabled on the router interfaces? That is something you should disable because it is a security risk.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have disabled proxy ARP (`no ip proxy-arp`).

Comment: It's a double negative so I think this means proxyarp is enabled on the inside interface:-

no sysopt noproxyarp inside

however there are still some machines on this internal network that are natted and apparently disabling proxy arp will break that. So I probably need to try this change out out of hours.

Possibly of interest is that I've been adding nat rules like this for the vpn:-

nat (inside,any) source static obj-10.1xx.200.0 obj-10.1xx.200.0 destination static obj-10.2xx.0.0 obj-10.2xx.0.0 no-proxy-arp route-lookup

Comment: You should not use NAT unless it is absolutely required. That would only be for public<->private addressing and overlapping addressing, but if you have overlapping addressing, then you need to correct that situation. NAT is not a substitute for routing.

Comment: Proxy ARP means different things to the ASA (and PIX) Just turning it off can make a lot of things stop working - almost at random. The crap that is "new-nat" removed all the nat0 stuff, so it's a mess to selectively nat traffic.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause, I'd added a nat disabling line that didn't include no-proxy-arp:-

nat (outside,any) source static DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3 DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3 destination static AWS_ALL AWS_ALL

Comment: Please accept your answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin I seemed to create this question as a user user62679 and I don't know how to login as them to select answered.

Comment: Ask about that on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ There is a way to merge the users, but I'm not sure how to do it.